# validate a state dropdownlist if the US is selected as a country in another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html-select

Need some advice I am trying to write a validator which only fires when a specific value in a dropdownlist is selected.

I have two drop down lists on this form one for Countries and the other for US States, the States dropdownlist only shows when the United States is selected from the Countries dropdownlist.

I need a validator that makes the State dropdownlist list a required field only if the United States is selected as a country.

As background information this a MVC3 Web Application and the show/hide code for the States dropdownlist is JQuery.

Comment: have been trying to use the Foolproof Validation NuGet package to add a RequiredIf to the validation model State field in my projects Business Logic Domain project, have also attempted to use JQuery to validate the dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to dynamically add the rule to jQuery for validation.
You would need to check on the server side this custom logic as well however.
You can do this in your controller, or ideally your VieWModel would implement IValidateableObject to check if country="usa" then county is required.

Use jQuery's .rules.add and .remove:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules

So you could do something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="usa")
        {
          $("#yourCountyDropDown").rules("add", {
           required: true,
           messages: {
             required: "County is required"
           }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          $("#yourCountyDropDown").rules("remove");
        }
    });
});
```

and for your ViewModel

```
public class WhateverYourObjectNameCreateViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
       #region Validation
        public IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (this.Country=="USA" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.County))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("County is required");
            }
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: It's not the country that's the required field I need to validate, the state is the required field due to way that MasterCard processes it payments, the country field is already required as standard, need to check if the state has been selected if the country selected is USA

Comment: doh sorry, easy enough - I had 'County" being validated when COUNTRY =usa, so simply change "County" to "State".

Comment: Also using an extension of Darin's method below you can get client side validation as well - see: https://gist.github.com/1547191

Comment: have edited the code to validate State, are the changes I have made correct?

Comment: have decided to go with validation in my ViewModel, have added the IEnumerable ValidationResult to my ViewModel how to I get it work within the View? Could I use the @Html.ValidationMessageFor as in Darin's example?

Comment: in my view I currently have a @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardHolder.State, (SelectList) ViewBag.States) field which displays the list of states. How do I get the validation which I have in the ViewModel to work with it associated dropdownlist?

Comment: just realized I need both parts for the validation to work? do I need put anything in the view to get the validation to fire for a example a validationmessagefor or a script link?

Comment: If you use IValidateableObject, you just need a validation summary at the top of the screen (to display general messages) or a Html.ValidationFor on each item. If you use Html.ValidationFor and you use the ValidationResult, you will need to tell the ValidationResult which property you are mapping to so it can display next to the "State" field- see: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public RequiredIfAttribute(string otherProperty, object otherPropertyValue)
    {
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
        OtherPropertyValue = otherPropertyValue;
    }

    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }
    public object OtherPropertyValue { get; private set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
        if (property == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", OtherProperty));
        }

        object otherPropertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (!object.Equals(OtherPropertyValue, otherPropertyValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

Now you could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Country", "usa", ErrorMessage = "Please select a state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "fr", Text = "France" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "usa", Text = "United States" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "spa", Text = "Spain" },
            };
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "al", Text = "Alabama" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "ak", Text = "Alaska" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "az", Text = "Arizona" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, Model.Countries, "-- Country --")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Country)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, Model.States, "-- State --")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.State)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

You might also find the [Foolproof package](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) of validation attributes useful.

Comment: Thanks Darin, only one slight problem, both the countries list and the states list are both coming from a database, plus I already have view model which pulls through values from two different tables both defined in the domain model, would ideally need the validation to be defined in the domain model plus have error messages coming from a resources.resx file were my errors are currently defined

Comment: Might it be worth creating a second view model for the validator or use the current view model and edit the domain model if the RequiredIf?

Comment: In all cases you need to use a view model. If you already have some existing view model then adapt it in order to be able to decorate the corresponding property with the custom validator. As far as the localized error message is concerned simply use the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` properties on the custom validation attribute, the same way you would use them for example on a standard Required attribute.